# Hangfire doesnt work anymore after publishing the project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, hangfire

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC 5. .NET Framework has the version 4.5. 
After I published my Project, Hangfire doesnt work anymore. So my recurring Tasks wont work. When I enter www.{myurl}/Hangfire, I'm getting a blank site.
The conenction String doesn't throw an error.

```
config.UseSqlServerStorage("Server={myServer}.database.windows.net,1433;Database={myDatabase};User ID={myUserId};Password={MyPassword};Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;");
config.UseServer();
```

So where could the problem be? When I run my project on localhost, it works fine. 
I'm using the same database on localhost and on my published version of the project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remote requests to Hangfire Dashboard are denied by default – it is very simple to forget about authorization before publicating it to the production environment.

You can either use [Hangfire.Dashboard.Authorization](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire.Dashboard.Authorization) package to configure the authorization based on users, roles, claims or basic authentication; or create your own authorization filter as shown below.

```
using Hangfire.Dashboard;

public class MyRestrictiveAuthorizationFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public bool Authorize(IDictionary<string, object> owinEnvironment)
    {
        // In case you need an OWIN context, use the next line.
        // `OwinContext` class is defined in the `Microsoft.Owin` package.
        var context = new OwinContext(owinEnvironment);

        return false; // or `true` to allow access
    }
}
```

After creating authorization filter, register it:

```
app.UseHangfire(config => 
{
    config.UseAuthorizationFilters(new MyRestrictiveAuthorizationFilter());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not good practice, but you can use the following code to allow all users

```
app.UseHangfire(config =>
{
    config.UseAuthorizationFilters(); //allow all users to access the dashboard
});
```

code [from](http://frankouimette.com/tutorial-installing-hangfire-without-asp-net-mvc/)